# How to change base_url settings with phpMyAdmin

Tags: magento, base-url

i have changed base_url in magento back end. Now my website is inaccessible

How to change base_url settings with my phpMyAdmin?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look @ http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/recover/restore_base_url_settings

1. Open your core_config_data table in phpMyAdmin.
2. Find the following rows for your unsecure section, they should look like the following:

   ```
   PATH                    VALUE
   web/unsecure/base_url   http://www.mydomain.com/
   ```
3. Replace `http://www.mydomain.com/` with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you’ve installed in a subfolder append it with a / after it.

Answer (score 3):

In your database, go to the `core_config_data` table and set the right `value` for those `path` values :  `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`

Answer (score 1):

If you change Base Url of your site which you set at the time installing Magento then there are possibilities that you can’t get the login page of Magento because you set invalid address for base url.Try the following to overcome from this problem:

Open **core_config_data** table from your Magento database tables in **PhpMyAdmin** Tool.

Now set the base url in **web/secure/base_url** and **web/unsecure/base_url**.

After performing all the above steps you need to delete cache files inside **var/cache** folder in root directory and also **session** files.

Answer (score 0):

if you're willing to do it via mysql command line:
open up terminal...

```
mysql -uroot;
```

Copy and paste the following into your terminal but make the necessary changes... obviously...

```
SET @db       = 'your_magento_db_name';

SET @old_url  = 'old_url';

SET @new_url  = 'new_url';

SET @q = CONCAT('UPDATE ', @db, '.core_config_data SET value = REPLACE(value,"',@old_url,'","',@new_url,'")');

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;

EXECUTE stmt;

SET @q        = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',@db,'.core_config_data WHERE value LIKE "%',@new_url,'%"');

PREPARE stmt FROM @q;

EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've hit this issue when working with phpmyadmin that's being accessed by an Ingress Nginx in a Kubernetes cluster.  The solution was setting the following env variable inside PhpMyAdmin pod to the new base url: `PMA_ABSOLUTE_URI`