# Nothing has been saving on my magento website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite, magento-1.7

i have encountered on a very weird situations in magento. I uploaded my magento website to a shared hosting(Folder name => abc/balaji/). Everything was working fine but when i added it with a domain then after i logged into my admin panel and saving anything whether it is a product,category,static blocks or deleting anything then nothing has been changing at all and When i checked the website through firebug and it shown me that the request first implemented through post(Contains index.php in the requested url) and then it moved permanently 302 to get request(without index.php). I have used several others htaccess in my website but still it is of no use. Sometimes i am getting 404 errors when using others htaccess. Below is my htacess file.

```
############################################
## These options are useful for development
#php_flag display_startup_errors on
#php_flag display_errors on
#php_flag html_errors on
#php_flag log_errors on
#php_flag log_errors_max_len 0
#php_value error_log /var/www/magento-lite/var/log/php_errors.log

############################################


############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

# Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
# AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
## cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

php_value memory_limit 128M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

#php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

# Insert filter on all content
###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
#BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
#Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

RewriteBase /

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

# RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
#RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /index.php/admin/$1 [L]
#RewriteRule ^index.php/admin/(.*)$ /admin/$1 [L,R]

# These lines are needed to prevent Apache from serving
# up the /admin folders directory index when a request is
# made for "/admin" or "/admin/".



############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.http://balajisolarsystems.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^.balajisolarsystems.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.balajisolarsystems.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*) $1 [R=301,QSA,L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

#FileETag none
```

I am stucked from 2 days and not able to find any kinds of solution till now. Please help me.

Comment: Hello,

First please check you server is compatible for magento or not?

Comment: My server is compatible with magento as i installed the magento website on my server it worked well but when i added my website with a domain then i am facing a problem in my admin panel

Comment: Could you explain "but when i added my website with a domain". Did you update your base_url. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16940717/how-to-change-base-url-settings-with-phpmyadmin

Comment: I already configured the base url(Secure and unsecure) in my database. I wanted to say when i added a domain name eg http://domains.com with my magento folder(abc/balaji) then it is creating a problem in my admin panel.